# URL duplicating itself

Tags: php, url, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if you know why suddenly when I go to my subdomain's website, it duplicates its URL and ends up giving me an error? This is the correct URL https://unexpectedfriends.vanessamdesign.com, but it comes up as this https://unexpectedfriends.vanessamdesign.com/unexpectedfriends.vanessamdesign.com/. When this happens, my site shows as broken as if I had no css setup correctly.

Comment: do you mean other than the https:// ? if so then no, but let me know if I misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

I contacted godaddy and the guy added an .htaccess file and that solved it. Good to know for the future if it happens to anyone else.